# How to rerun a request for an input after invalid input in Java?

Tags: java, input

I am looking for a solution that only allows either the answer 1 or 2. 
How can one request for the input again if another answer in entered instead?
Thanks!

```
System.out.println("Are you single or married? \n 1 - Single \n 2 - Married");

    status = in.nextInt(); //allow input for status
```

Comment: try looking up `while` and `break` statements.

Comment: how would that work @ajb?

Comment: +1 .. why negative vote.. this sounds  beginner level legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{
System.out.println("Are you single or married? \n 1 - Single \n 2 - Married");
status = in.nextInt(); //allow input for status
}while((status!=1)&&(status!=2));
```

This will continue to print the same question until the answer is either 1 or 2. You may want to add a `System.out.print("\f");` to clear the screen just before you ask the question for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it, but I'd recommend doing some research yourself, as I'm sure you could come up with an answer that is more to your liking:

```
boolean right=false;
do{
System.out.println("Are you single or married? \n 1 - Single \n 2 - Married");
status = in.nextInt();
if(status.equals("1") || status.equals("2");{right=true;}
}
while(status==false);
```

I'd recommend researching `while` loops and `if-statements`:

- [while loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.htm)
- [if-statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

Warning: I didn't test this code

```
while(true)
{
  System.out.println("Are you single or married? \n 1 - Single \n 2 - Married");
  status = in.nextInt(); // allow input for status

  if(status==1 || status==2)
      break;

}
```